# Gradient Color Stops in Tailwind not working on view component in React Native

Tags: react-native, background, tailwind-css, gradient, background-color

I've been making a simple container component in React Native where I want a background with a gradient. I´m using tailwind but for some reason it doesn't recognise it. I have tried:

```
    <View style={tw`bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500`}>
      {children}
    </View>
```

I have also tried too do it like this:

```
    <View style={tw.style(`bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500`)}>
      {children}
    </View>
```

Both shows nothing unfortunately. I'm suspecting its how I use Tailwind on a View component.

Comment: React Native does not support 3rd-party CSS libraries. Tailwind is web-only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is React Native (View) doesn't support gradient background. You need to use npm package such as:

1. [`react-native-linear-gradient`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient) OR
2. [`expo-linear-gradient`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/)